# How to copy files from an absolute path to docker image using docker maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, docker, path, dockerfile

I am writing microservices with Java. At the end, I run maven build to generate a Docker image based on a Dockerfile in directory [project-root]/docker. Some files need to be copied into the Docker image. Therefore I have the following lines in my Dockerfile:

```
# HDFS base image
FROM mdouchement/hdfs
COPY ${workdir.name} /${workdir.name}
COPY ${resource.dir} /etc/hadoop
```

Variables `workdir.name` and `resource.dir` are defined in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <workdir.name>javarun</workdir.name>
        <resource.dir>${project.baseUri}/src/main/resources</resource.dir>
</properties>
```

While first copy command uses relative path which is equivalent to `target/docker/javarun`, second command uses absolute path.

It turns out the first `COPY` works while I got error for the second `COPY` saying the directory is not found:

```
[INFO] Building image docker.repo.lgc.com/distarch/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs
Step 1/3 : FROM mdouchement/hdfs
 ---> c95344e8749d
Step 2/3 : COPY javarun /javarun
 ---> e2e8cb5bc21f
Removing intermediate container f49da68fe77e
Step 3/3 : COPY file:/C:/Users/H184870/Workspace/core/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs//src/main/resources /etc/hadoop
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.906 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-20T11:07:12-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.3.10:build (docker-build) on project com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs: 
Exception caught: lstat file:/C:/Users/H184870/Workspace/core/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs//src/main/resources: no such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

The path printed out is `/C:/Users/H184870/Workspace/core/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs//src/main/resources` which looks weird. My guess is this is not a valid Windows path.

I am running it on a Windows machine now, but the build process will eventually moved to a Linux server. How do I make an absolute path compatible with both OS when copying files in Dockerfile?

**EDIT**  Originally thought it was a windows path issue, so tried to build it on Linux and got the same error.

According to [this post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592#issuecomment-282702580), the src path should be the relative path from build context. That's why the absolute path does not work. But what is the default `PATH` of docker build? Is it the same as the directory where Dockerfile is located?

Comment: When is /etc/hadoop created in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @user2915097 It pulls mdouchement/hdfs as base image, that part was left out in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare the second variable as:

```
<resource.dir>${project.baseDir}/src/main/resources</resource.dir>
```

With baseDir.

Comment: Changed to `basedir` (Dir does not work) and still getting the same error. According to [this](https://github.com/cko/predefined_maven_properties/blob/master/README.md) `basedir` is deprecated.

Comment: ${basedir} is deprecated but ${project.basedir} isn't it.

Comment: I did try `project.basedir` and still the same. One difference I noticed with `basedir` is it prints out the windows-like path `Step 3/3 : COPY C:\\Users\\H184870\\Workspace\\core\\com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service.hdfs/src/main/resources /etc/hadoop`

Answer (score 0):

Include the shared/common resources in your pom  by adding:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>/absolute/path/to/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>shared</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then (if using spotify Dockerfile maven plugin) add the resource path on build as a build argument

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <buildArgs>
        ...
        <SHARED_RESOURCES>target/classes/shared</SHARED_RESOURCES>
    </buildArgs>
</configuration>
```

Then use it in Dockerfile as such:

```
...
ARG SHARED_RESOURCES
COPY ${SHARED_RESOURCES}/something /target
...
```